# Php pass by reference in recursive call

Tags: php, recursion

I have a method with reference in param. But when I'm trying to do recursive call, no values are saved to my array, although there should be 2 values in array. Here is my function, the problem is, when it's called again while checking `$nodesArray[$nodeKey]['nodes']`. That should check menu sub-nodes and give back that nodes, which the selected role can see. At the end of every foreach loop, I use `dump($nodesArray)`. After last loop when checking subnodes, array has only the right values. But when it gets back to "main" loop, value of `['nodes']` is `NULL`. What could be wrong? Thank you!

```
private function filterMenuNodesByRole(& $nodesArray)
{
    foreach ($nodesArray as $nodeKey => $nodeItem) {
        $link = trim($nodeItem['href'], self::SEPARATOR_PRESENTER_LINK);

        if ((substr($link, -1) == '!') && ($this->user->isInRole(AuthRoleEnum::SUPERADMIN) === false)) {
            unset($nodesArray[$nodeKey]);
        }

        if (substr_count($link, self::SEPARATOR_PRESENTER_LINK) == 2) {
            $resource = substr($link, 0, strrpos($link, self::SEPARATOR_PRESENTER_LINK));
            $privilege = substr($link, strrpos($link, self::SEPARATOR_PRESENTER_LINK) + 1);

            if ($this->user->isAllowed($resource, $privilege) === false) {
                unset($nodesArray[$nodeKey]);
            } else if (!empty($nodeItem['nodes'])) {
                $nodesArray[$nodeKey]['nodes'] = $this->filterMenuNodesByRole($nodeItem['nodes']);
            }
        } else {
            if (!empty($nodeItem['nodes'])) {
                $nodesArray[$nodeKey]['nodes'] = $this->filterMenuNodesByRole($nodeItem['nodes']);
            }
        }

        if (isset($nodeItem['nodes']) && count($nodeItem['nodes']) == 0) {
            unset($nodesArray[$nodeKey]);
            continue;
        }
        dump($nodesArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning a return value to 'nodes', but the function doesn't return anything -> which results in the NULL.

`$nodesArray[$nodeKey]['nodes'] = $this->filterMenuNodesByRole($nodeItem['nodes']);`
should be
`$this->filterMenuNodesByRole($nodeItem['nodes']);`

but when you run the code now, it seems like the results of the recursion are ignored. The solution for this is to change the way your foreach works

`foreach ($nodesArray as $nodeKey => & $nodeItem) {`

this way, any changes to `$nodeItem` wil be persistent.